# How can I create a BufferGeometry from an Object3D?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I create a BufferGeometry from an Object3D I've created with OBJLoader? I'm doing this as the geometry is available as an OBJ file, but I want to be able to update faces one by one.

I tried with

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(geometry))
// Object3D

var bgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry )
// throws: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

and

```
var bgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
bgeometry.setFromObject(geometry);
console.log(bgeometry.faces);
// bgeometry.faces is undefined
```

What am I missing from the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bit of a misunderstanding. `BufferGeometry` does not have a `faces` property. Maybe you want to convert a `BufferGeometry`  to `Geometry`, instead? `OBJLoader` does parse the geometry data into instances of `BufferGeometry`. Try to convert the resulting geometries like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( bufferGeometry );
```

You now can access [geometry.faces](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry.faces);